# How to deduce the merge target branch during the Pull Request build in vNext?

Tags: git, tfs, build, pull-request

We are in the process of migrating our code from the TFS version control to Git (hosted by the TFS). Part of the migration is setting up the Pull Request builds.

We use TFS vNext CI framework.

And we have it working, when a Pull Request is created, the build starts, as expected.

For example, this is how the Git repository history on the PR build server can look like after the build starts:

```
PS D:\_wf\02\1\s> git lg -5
*   92d0a7efc |  (HEAD, pull/505/merge) Merge pull request 505 from canws211_master1 into master (2 hours ago) [Lopyreva, Valeria]
|\
| * 37103b362 |  (origin/canws211_master1) test (16 hours ago) [Lopyreva, Valeria]
| * ca6601027 |  test (17 hours ago) [Lopyreva, Valeria]
* |   50045719d |  (origin/master) Merged PR 504: Fix the path references. (2 hours ago) [Kharitonov, Mark]
|\ \
| * | bf3814458 |  (origin/shelve_test) Fix the path references. (18 hours ago) [Kharitonov, Mark]
PS D:\_wf\02\1\s>
```

A very important logic of the PR build is to figure out which files are touched by the Pull Request. Given the example above, this can be determined like this:

```
PS D:\_wf\02\1\s> git diff-tree --name-status origin/master..
M       Build
```

Now, the problem. How do I infer the merge target from the build itself?

I can define a dedicated build parameter and pass the merge target there. But I feel this is wrong. The merge target should be available somehow.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Trying to clarify. The build script needs to know which files are modified in the Pull Request. The way to do it is:

```
git diff-tree --name-status -r <MERGE_TARGET>..
```

Where `<MERGE_TARGET>` should be replaced with the merge target. So, if the PR is for master, then it would be `origin/master`. But if it is for branch called YabaDabaDoo, then it would be `origin/YabaDabaDoo`. My problem is that I want to deduce the merge target automatically from within a vNext Git build.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Added a clarification. Is it better now?

Comment: @mark Have you resolved the issue by Daniel's answer? any update?

Comment: Yup, I have just posted our solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up placing the following inline powershell script:

```
$TargetBranch = $env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_TARGETBRANCH
if ($TargetBranch)
{
    $TargetBranch = $TargetBranch.Split('/')[-1]
}
else
{
    $TargetBranch = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
}
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branch]$(git remote show -n)/$TargetBranch"
```

This generates a `branch` variable , so `$(branch)` equals exactly what we need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get the PR information, which includes the source and target branches.